# Creating a PHP web server... executing PHP files

Tags: php, fastcgi

I'm making a simple web server using PHP and sockets. Everything is working fine right now (static content only). I'm interested in supporting the execution of PHP files.

How would I go about doing this? I don't really want to use `eval($fileContents)` since that does not seem very secure. Is there some way that I can use FastCGI sockets or something?

What about PHP-CGI?

---

I've decided on using FastCGI, so
here's a more specific question:

How do I pass files into PHP-CGI and get the output as a string?
`php-cgi "phpinfo.php"` outputs HTML content like I want.

I understand that I can use sockets but I can't seem to find out what to send into that socket to get the output.

Thanks

Comment: Why on earth would you do this?

Comment: Wes, you're so delicate.

Comment: Wow, someone actually did this for real: http://nanoweb.si.kz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what's so insecure in eval($fileContents)? or, more familiar but actually equal include $fileName?
(with proper filename sanitizing of course)

apparently it's no more insane than PHP web server itself.

Comment: Any errors which are present in included files stop the entire server. Should I just use exceptions?

Just something that's annoying: phpinfo() does not output HTML content when running php-cli. PHP-CGI seems to do it though...

Comment: Well yeah, a most common way to connect web-server with some executable is CGI

Answer (score 0):

You could exec() the PHP executable from within your web server. Though you'd also have to finagle the passing of GPC data to the script in question.